# It is possible for one iCal event to refer to another?

Tags: icalendar

I am trying to create a recurring event for submitting invoices.

This day occurs on the first Wednesday that follows the end of the billing cycle.

The billing cycle is the last Friday of the month.

This means that the recurring event for submitting invoices may be the *last* Wednesday of the month **or** the *first* Wednesday of the month.

Can the iCal schema handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a RRULE like this to refer to the last wednesday of the month:

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYWEEKDAY=-1WE
```

For the first wednesday of the month:

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYWEEKDAY=1WE
```

But there's no syntax in RRULE to say: the first wednesday after the last friday of the month.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is anyway of selecting a particular RRULE based on a condition? i.e. select the first rule if the month contains 5 Wednesdays and the second rule otherwise?

Comment: There's not. This is really the extent of how flexible this is unfortunately.

Comment: You can however select for the 5th wednesday, which will be ignored for months that don't have a 5th wednesday. I think your only real option is to manually specify all the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion: categorically no it cannot (see Evert's answer which I have accepted due to confirmation in its comments).